# substitutions of variables in double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I got a function bounded between $$xy=1$$ $$xy =4$$ $$x^2-y^2=1$$ $$x^2-y^2=4$$ 
and the double integral is 
$$\int_{D} xy(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy  $$
I tried substituting $xy$ with $v$ and $x^2-y^2= u$, 
but when I tried to solve for $x$ or for $y$, I couldn't.
I also tried opening $x^2-y^2$ to $(x-y)(x+y)=1$ or $4$ and then putting in the integral but I didn't work for me either 
I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint for the substitution needed.

Comment: Hint: What is the Jacobian of this substitution?

Comment: @PeterForeman (-2y^2-2x^2)^(-1)

Comment: Yes so that means that$$(x^2+y^2)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\frac12\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$

Comment: @PeterForeman ohh i got it now! thank you so much i tried it for an hour! cant belive i didnt see that